# Is is possible to read from an input file and convert each line of the text file into a vector of strings?

Tags: clojure

I have a text file as shown below:

```
---#--###----
-#---#----##-
####-#-#-#-##
---#---#-#---
-#-####---##-
-#------#----
-############
------------@
```

Can I read from the input file and get an output in this format

```
[ ["-" "-" "-" "#" "-" "-" "#" "#" "#" "-" "-" "-" "-"] 
  ["-" "#" "-" "-" "-" "#" "-" "-" "-" "-" "#" "#" "-"] 
  ["#" "#" "#" "#" "-" "#" "-" "#" "-" "#" "-" "#" "#"] 
  ["-" "-" "-" "#" "-" "-" "-" "#" "-" "#" "-" "-" "-"] 
  ["-" "#" "-" "#" "#" "#" "#" "-" "-" "-" "#" "#" "-"] 
  ["-" "#" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "#" "-" "-" "-" "-"] 
  ["-" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#"] 
  ["-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "@"]
]
```

I tried reading the input file line by line and adding to a vector:

```
    (defn loadFile2 []
        (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader "map.txt")]
        (reduce conj [] (line-seq rdr)))
    )

    (defn convert_input_to_string []
        "Converts"
        ;(def temp )
        (loop [i 0 temp (loadFile2)]
            (if (< i (count temp))

            (recur (inc i) (assoc temp i (str (join (seq (get temp 
             i))))) )
            temp
            ))
    )

(convert_input_to_string).
```

This approach gives me a vector of strings:

```
[---#--###---- 
 -#---#----##- 
 ####-#-#-#-## 
 ---#---#-#--- 
 -#-####---##- 
 -#------#---- 
 -############ 
 ------------@
]
```

I want the vector in this format:

```
[ ["-" "-" "-" "#" "-" "-" "#" "#" "#" "-" "-" "-" "-"] 
  ["-" "#" "-" "-" "-" "#" "-" "-" "-" "-" "#" "#" "-"] 
  ["#" "#" "#" "#" "-" "#" "-" "#" "-" "#" "-" "#" "#"] 
  ["-" "-" "-" "#" "-" "-" "-" "#" "-" "#" "-" "-" "-"] 
  ["-" "#" "-" "#" "#" "#" "#" "-" "-" "-" "#" "#" "-"] 
  ["-" "#" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "#" "-" "-" "-" "-"] 
  ["-" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#"] 
  ["-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "@"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Go step by step.

Read data (As file is small, just slurp). Let's name the file `grid.txt`

```
(slurp "grid.txt")
"---#--###----\r\n-#---#----##-\r\n####-#-#-#-##\r\n---#---#-#---\r\n-#-####---##-\r\n-#------#----\r\n-############\r\n------------@"
```

Break into lines:

```
(->> (slurp "grid.txt") 
     (clojure.string/split-lines))
["---#--###----" "-#---#----##-" "####-#-#-#-##" "---#---#-#---" "-#-####---##-" "-#------#----" "-############" "------------@"]
```

Convert each string to character vector:

```
(->> (slurp "grid.txt") 
     (clojure.string/split-lines) 
     (map vec))
([\- \- \- \# \- \- \# \# \# \- \- \- \-] [\- \# \- \- \- \# \- \- \- \- \# \# \-] [\# \# \# \# \- \# \- \# \- \# \- \# \#] [\- \- \- \# \- \- \- \# \- \# \- \- \-] [\- \# \- \# \# \# \# \- \- \- \# \# \-] [\- \# \- \- \- \- \- \- \# \- \- \- \-] [\- \# \# \# \# \# \# \# \# \# \# \# \#] [\- \- \- \- \- \- \- \- \- \- \- \- \@])
```

Convert top level to vector:

```
(->> (slurp "grid.txt") 
     (clojure.string/split-lines) 
     (map vec) 
     (into []))
[[\- \- \- \# \- \- \# \# \# \- \- \- \-] [\- \# \- \- \- \# \- \- \- \- \# \# \-] [\# \# \# \# \- \# \- \# \- \# \- \# \#] [\- \- \- \# \- \- \- \# \- \# \- \- \-] [\- \# \- \# \# \# \# \- \- \- \# \# \-] [\- \# \- \- \- \- \- \- \# \- \- \- \-] [\- \# \# \# \# \# \# \# \# \# \# \# \#] [\- \- \- \- \- \- \- \- \- \- \- \- \@]]
```

Note that this isn't the same as your expected output because the inner vectors contain characters, not strings.

If you really wanted strings instead, you Need to add a line:

```
(->> (slurp "grid.txt") 
     (clojure.string/split-lines) 
     (map #(map str %)) 
     (map vec) 
     (into []))
[["-" "-" "-" "#" "-" "-" "#" "#" "#" "-" "-" "-" "-"] ["-" "#" "-" "-" "-" "#" "-" "-" "-" "-" "#" "#" "-"] ["#" "#" "#" "#" "-" "#" "-" "#" "-" "#" "-" "#" "#"] ["-" "-" "-" "#" "-" "-" "-" "#" "-" "#" "-" "-" "-"] ["-" "#" "-" "#" "#" "#" "#" "-" "-" "-" "#" "#" "-"] ["-" "#" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "#" "-" "-" "-" "-"] ["-" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#"] ["-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "@"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

the simplest would be something like this:

```
(with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader "data.txt")]
  (mapv vec (line-seq rdr)))
```

or in case you need strings instead of chars:

```
(with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader "data.txt")]
  (mapv #(clojure.string/split % #"") (line-seq rdr)))
```

both return vector of vectors of elements

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford to load the whole input file in memory, here's a quick-and-dirty function that does just that:

```
(defn read-vec-of-strings [filename]
  (let [contents (slurp filename)                      ;; see (1) below
        lines    (clojure.string/split contents #"\n") ;; see (2) below
        vectors  (mapv #(mapv str %) lines)]           ;; see (3) below
    vectors))
```

- Step (1) loads the whole file as a single string in memory;
- Step (2) splits the file by newlines;
- Step (3) is where the magic happens: for each line in the file (`mapv ... lines`), call another (anonymous) function `#(mapv str %)` that iterates through each character of the line and turns them into a string (so the character `\#` becomes the string `"#"`), and accumulate the result in a vector.

I saved your input file as `input.txt` and called the function like this:

```
>  (clojure.pprint/pprint (read-vec-of-strings "input.txt"))

[["-" "-" "-" "#" "-" "-" "#" "#" "#" "-" "-" "-" "-"]
 ["-" "#" "-" "-" "-" "#" "-" "-" "-" "-" "#" "#" "-"]
 ["#" "#" "#" "#" "-" "#" "-" "#" "-" "#" "-" "#" "#"]
 ["-" "-" "-" "#" "-" "-" "-" "#" "-" "#" "-" "-" "-"]
 ["-" "#" "-" "#" "#" "#" "#" "-" "-" "-" "#" "#" "-"]
 ["-" "#" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "#" "-" "-" "-" "-"]
 ["-" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#" "#"]
 ["-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" "@"]]
nil
```